# Hypogeometric Probabilities not adding to one

Tags: statistics

[image]

When I was computing the Hypogeometric formula probabilities I was having a little difficulty following the solutions manual.

I attempted to compute the event where there was one Red Chip and One White Chip and the probability turned out to be .26667.

The Solutions manual says other wise saying the probability is .53

.26 wouldn't make the cut for the Hypo-geometric probabilities to equal one.

I'm a bit confused on what i'm supposed to do here and why is it .53?

Zero Whites (6/10)(5/9)=.33

One White (4/10)(6/9) or (6/10)(4/9)=.26667

Two Whites (4/10)(3/9)=.13

Comment: You do not show your calculation, so I will have to guess. Maybe you decided that the probability the "first" is red and the "second" is white is $(6/10)(4/9)$. But "first" could be white and "second" red. The calculation shown in your post avoids that trap by using binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Where you wrote "or", you then took one of the two (equal) probabilities instead of adding them. Here "or" doesn't mean that you can use either the first *or* the second form of calculation, but that either the event "first one white, then one black" *or* the event "first one black, then one white" could occur. These are two distinct and mutually exclusive events, both yielding the result "one white"; so by the [addition law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Further_consequences) you need to add them; that yields the missing factor of $2$.